# View real-time logs from NAOqi application with SSH

Tags: pepper

Is it possible to view logs from my application without using Choregraphe?
At the moment I am limited to log files from '/var/log/naoqi/servicemanager/'.
I am implementing qi.logger() and would like to connect to the robot IP with SSH and get logs from a specific service.

```
qicli log-view
```

only shows system logs. I would like to attach the logger to a my application, maybe using the serivce PID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to log into a specific places, like for instance if you start it from an independant python script.

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='some_files.log',
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(levelname)s %(relativeCreated)6d %(threadName)s %(message)s (%(module)s.%(lineno)d)',
    filemode='w')
```

then some tail -f -n /var/log/naoqi/servicemanager/some_files.log

WRN: this is just an hint, I haven't tested this solution...

Comment: I ended up doing 'tail -f /var/log/naoqi/servicemanager/some_files.log'